# Android simulate touch

Tags: android, click, touch, simulate

I want to know how to make an app that runs in background that simulate touch on screen
 I dont have any knowledge   About making an android app.

What tools do i need.?  I really want to learn how to make an android app. 
I already search here i read such key event , touch event,

If i have written the codes where do i compile it to make a android program?

This is i want to make.
Example.

> If coordinate x:102  y:109 is RGB=234, 293, 234

Then begin touch event on coordinate `x:102 y: 109`
And

> If coordinate  x:102 y:109 is not RGB = 234, 293 v234

The begin click back button.
  I want also to  add  delays between the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

The IDE used is Eclipse. The site I linked has everything to get you started, including download links to the java sdks you need, and the ADK to compile your code to run on a device emulator.